# Windows CE ActiveSync TCP connection

Tags: c#-2.0, windows-ce, activesync, .net-cf-3.5

I have a .NET compact framework program that has my CE device open a socket to my PC over the USB cable's ActiveSync connection.  Everything works fine, except when I'm trying to use a laptop that isn't connected to a network.  Then the CE device throws a `SocketException` with an `ErrorCode = 10061`, which I tracked down as a `WSAECONNREFUSED -- Connection refused` error.

After a bit of debugging, I discovered that the exception was being thrown because the DNS lookup (using `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry`) was only returning a Loopback... and, obviously, the CE device isn't running the server code to accept the connection...

So, any ideas on how I could:  a) trick my computer into thinking it's on a network, b) reference the machine a CE device is connected to via ActiveSync in a manner other than by its hostname, or c) some other option I don't know about yet?

Comment: Check if the PC and WinCE device are both in the same subnet first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the hostname to resolve the PC.  Instead use 'ppp-peer'.

Comment: Perfect! I love simple solutions!  I just changed the hostname string to `PPP_PEER` and everything works.  Thanks!